# Adding A Row To An Empty GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a row inside an empty gridview, i tired the following code but no luck so far:

```
        GridViewRow oRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableCell oCell = new TableCell();
        oCell.Text = "XXX";
        oRow.Cells.Add(oCell);
        gvMemberShip.Controls.Add(oRow);
```

Note: i ran this code on Page_Load Event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way we did it is to extend the GridView. Override the CreateChildControls, with something like:

```
public class CustomGridView : GridView
{
    protected override int CreateChildControls(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
    {
        int numRows = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);
        //no data rows created, create empty table
        if (numRows == 0)
        {
            //create table
            Table table = new Table();
            table.ID = this.ID;

            //create a new header row
            GridViewRow row = base.CreateRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            //convert the exisiting columns into an array and initialize
            DataControlField[] fields = new DataControlField[this.Columns.Count];
            this.Columns.CopyTo(fields, 0);
            this.InitializeRow(row, fields);
            row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            this.Controls.Add(table);
        }
        return numRows;
    }
}
```

Overrides the GridView' CreateChildControls to Add an Empty table to it when there is no data to display.

Comment: This code produce an error for me "There is no suitable method to override", and second i honestly don't understand the purpose of this code so if somebody could explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DataSource of the GridView and initialize with a collection with only 1 element. 
If you do this in your Page_Load and then call DataBind() the GridView will show your row.

Comment: I don't want this in the datasource, what i am trying to achieve here is an Insert Row Capability.